# Grouping elements in the list based on a sum in tcl

Tags: tcl

i have a list

```
set num "20 10 40 50 25 15"
```

I want the outputs to be grouped such that sum of each group should not exceed 60.
In this case, outputting:

```
{20 40} {10 50} {25 15}
```

I've written the following snippet

```
set num "20 10 40 50 25 15"
for {set i 0} {$i < 4} {incr i} {
    for {set j 0} {$j < 4} {incr j} {
        if {$i == $j} {continue}
        if {[expr  [lindex $num $i] + [lindex $num $j] ] == 60 } {
        puts "[lindex $num $i]  [lindex $num $j]"}
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20  40
10  50
40  20
50  10
```

I am trying to remove the duplicates and trying to get the combination where the sum is less that 60

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: That's a fun little problem (if slightly under-specified), but does sound a lot like the sort of thing you'd do for a class and we don't want to interfere with your education. Can you show us what you've tried so we are helping you fix what you've done instead of outright solving it for you?

Comment: Hi Donal, I've posted the code which i've tried out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, it looks much better. I have made a few more edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to write a procedure that finds a maximal pair in the list, a second procedure that removes a pair of numbers from the list (while being careful about duplicates) and then put those together to do the overall task.

Splitting up tasks this way is one of the most important things that programmers learn to do. Getting it right takes practice and experience.

```
proc findPair {list limit} {
    # Variables to hold our best matches so far
    set maxval -inf;  # Negative infinity is less than every other number
    set maxpair {}

    for {set idx1 0} {$idx1 < [llength $list]} {incr idx1} {
        set v1 [lindex $list $idx1]

        # Optimization: make idx2 always greater than idx1
        for {set idx2 [expr {$idx1 + 1}]} {$idx2 < [llength $list]} {incr idx2} {
            set v2 [lindex $list $idx2]
            set sum [expr {$v1 + $v2}]

            if {($sum <= $limit) && ($sum > $maxval)} {
                # Save what we've found as our new best choice
                set maxval $sum
                set maxpair [list $v1 $v2]
            }
        }
    }
    # This variable now has the first, best option...
    # ... or the empty list if we can't find anything that satisfies.
    return $maxpair
}
```

You might wish to think about why I make sure that `$idx2` is always more than `$idx1` (what happens if they're the other way round; why don't I care about that case?).

```
proc removePair {listvar pair} {
    # Make variable in caller also be a variable here; THIS IS CLEVER MAGIC
    upvar 1 $listvar list

    foreach value $pair {
        # Find where the value is
        set idx [lsearch -exact $list $value]
        # Remove the element at the $idx'th position
        set list [lreplace $list $idx $idx]
    }
}
```

Now that we have those, we can do the overall problem:

```
set numbers {20 10 40 50 25 15}
set limit 60

while {[llength $numbers] > 0} {
    set pair [findPair $numbers $limit]
    if {[llength $pair] > 0} {
        # We've found another pair. Great! Print it out
        puts "found pair: $pair"
        # NO ‘$’ in front of ‘numbers’; we are passing the VARIABLE NAME not the contents
        removePair numbers $pair
    } else {
        # No possible pairs left! This is a failure case
        puts "remaining unpairable numbers: $numbers"
        # Stop the search
        break
    }
}
```

The output from that is:

```
found pair: 20 40
found pair: 10 50
found pair: 25 15
```

which looks OK to me.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been better to leave some to-dos and blanks in the solution, rather than to give one complete solution? Just asking what the conventions here are, after having read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions-

Answer (score 0):

I share the impression that this is a classic course assignment, and that the question  is missing details relevant to discussing an adequate solution (e.g., any constraints on space vs. time complexity, duplicated elements etc.).

While Donal's answer is complete in itself, it is just one possible shot from many. A more conventional solution schema here (assuming, an in-place solution is sought), involves:

1. Start from a sorted list (which sets the overall complexity to that of Tcl's `[lsort]`).
2. Iterate over this sorted list from two directions, i.e., from its head and its tail, till their overlap.
3. For each candidate pair of current head and tail, decide whether the constraints are met (e.g., pair-sum limit). Depending on the decision, proceed by moving forward either head or tail indices (using `incr`).

A possible skeleton could look like this:

```
proc pairwiseByCappedPairSum {list limit} {

    set list [lsort -integer $list]; # use -unique flag in case of duplicates
    set fromStart 0
    set fromEnd 0

    while {$fromStart < ([llength $list]-$fromEnd-1)} {
        set v1 [lindex $list $fromStart]
        set v2 [lindex $list end-$fromEnd]

        ## ENTER YOUR FRAGMENT HERE:
        ## -------------------------
        # if {...} {
        #   incr fromEnd
        # } else {
        #    puts [list $v1 ...]
        #    incr fromStart
        # }
    }
}
```

When completed, and called this way:

```
set num "20 10 40 50 25 15"
set limit 60
pairwiseByCappedPairSum $num $limit
```

it should print out:

```
10 {15 20 25 40 50}
15 {20 25 40}
20 {25 40}
```

which looks okay to me.